# What does "close (1)" describe in questions?

Tags: support, questions

I asked [How to use hook_form_search_block_form_alter?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208214/from-where-to-get-a-code-which-to-be-used-in-hooks-plz-see-description) a while ago, and I found it says *close (1)* as shown in following image. If I hover on that, it shows *4 more votes are needed to close this question*. Was the question down-voted? Its score is not negative.

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users with 3000 reputation can [vote to close](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) questions; this is different from a downvote. The number between parenthesis is the number of users who voted to close the question. When 5 users vote to close a question, the question gets closed.

If you click on the *close (1)* link, you should be able to see which reason was picked in the dialog to close the question. These reasons are explained in [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Users with at least 250 reputation, but less than 3000, can vote to close their own questions, and see close votes on their own questions only. That is why you don't see *close (1)* in questions asked by other users.

Comment: Maybe you want to refine your answer by separating the 2 types of "vote to close": (a) the very first user who hit the "close" link (below a question) versus (b) users in the "close votes" review queue who voted (as part of such review) to close the question. More specifically: if you see (eg) close(3) below the question, that means 1 user as in "(a)", plus 2 users as in "(b)". So with that, what is the ultimate value of "x" for a question with "close(x)" to actually get "put on hold" (not yet closed ...)???

Comment: Ok, you're right, there could be multiple close votes "directly from the question" (as my "(a)")., I forgot about that Though I do think it's not possible that they ALL come from the review queue (as my "(b)"). Because what would the trigger be for a question to show up in the close review queue (if there was not at least 1 as my "(a)". Or do you think I am still missing something for that scenario/case?